# What is difference between Qmax and Design Capacity of battery parameters?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry, fuel-gauge

I'm working with the BQ27742-g1 (Texas Instruments) Fuel Gauge.

I have some confusion about battery parameters.

What is Qmax and Design capacity? Are they the same or different?

What is the configuration value for Qmax and Design capacity if my battery is single cell 4600 mAh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Design
Capacity**
1000
mAh
Set based
on the nominal
pack
capacity
as interpreted
from
cell manufacturer's
datasheet.
If multiple
parallel
cells
are used,
should
be set to N * Cell Capacity

**Qmax
Cell** 0
1000
mAh
Set to initial
configured
value
for Design
Capacity.
The gauge
will update
this
parameter
automatically
after
the optimization
cycle
and for every
regular
Qmax
update
thereafter.

Seems self-explanatory from the datasheet above